# Multi-Sig set permission vs Multi-sig propose transaction, do you need to specify the accounts in both?

Tags: accounts, multisig

So I created an MSIG account using set permissions

```
cleos set account permission msigact11113 active '{"threshold":2,"keys":[],"accounts":[
{"permission":{"actor":"permitact111","permission":"active"},"weight":2},
{"permission":{"actor":"permitact112","permission":"active"},"weight":1},
{"permission":{"actor":"permitact113","permission":"active"}, "weight":1},
{"permission":{"actor":"permitact114","permission":"active"},"weight":1}],
"waits":[]}' -p msigact11113@owner
```

and then propose the transaction

```
cleos multisig propose payme 
'[{"actor": "permitact111", "permission": "active"},{"actor": "permitact111", "permission": "active"}]' '[{"actor": "permitact113", "permission": "active"},{"actor": "permitact112", "permission": "active"}]' 
'[{"actor": "permitact113", "permission": "active"},{"actor": "permitact113", "permission": "active"}]'
'[{"actor": "permitact113", "permission": "active"},{"actor": "permitact114", "permission": "active"}]'
eosio.token transfer '{"from":"msigact11113", "to":"trustring121", "quantity":"100.00 CUV", "memo":"Trade Payment"}' -p msigact11113@owner
```

Since you already defined the accounts within the MSIG,  why to do you need to specify the msig accounts again in the proposal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a *msig-permission* and creating a *msig-proposal* are two different things, neither of which requires both (only in very specific cases).

When you add a *msig-permission* to an account, *as long as that permission exists* the accounts that have been added can perform actions. Depending on the thresholds of the permission, multiple accounts may need to sign the transaction *before* it is pushed to a BP and accepted as valid by the block producers. If it does not contain the necessary *authorization(s)*, it's not added to the block.

A *msig-action* *waits* in the msig-contract for the *required approvals* and then can be executed, each individual approval is going into a block. In addition, a msig-action contains a specific action, can only be executed once, and must be proposed again once it has been executed.